# correlation of 2 all vs all matrices on same variables R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a set of samples eg Sample1, Sample2, Sample3, Sample4

I have two distance matrices eg:

```
    S1    S2    S3    S4
S1  0     10    14    20

S2  52    0     100   30

S3  3     4      0    10

S4  55    100    2     0
```

I need to take the distance between each sample from both tables and correlate these eg with a scatter graph/linear regression (which I know how to do, it is just getting data out of the distance matrices (which are pre-computed from elsewhere) which I am struggling with.

Comment: Please use `dput()` to show your data!

Answer (score 0):

I am not complete sure what you want to do with the data. However to get the two matrix triangles you can use `upper.tri` and `lower.tri` like

```
m <- matrix(1:16, nrow=4)
m[upper.tri(m)]
m[lower.tri(m)]
```

Is this what you were looking for ?